# Importing geospatial PDFs with QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, import, pdf

I've been using GDAL to work with geospatial PDFs to make geotifs and have been running into some issues, so I started working with QGIS. A fine product I might add.

When I select a directory containing PDFs, the browser panel shows 2 PDFs listed for each actual PDF. One looks like a checkerboard and the other like a jellybean.

Dragging the jellybean to the work area pops up a window listing some layers from the PDF. When compared to the layers in the Acrobat view of the PDF, some are missing.

Dragging the PDF jellybean looking icon to the work area freezes the program. I believe that it is rendering.

Is there a way to get all layers to show and deselect the ones that I wish to remove?